# Why is this linked list crashing my IDE?

Tags: java, linked-list

I don't know what is wrong with this list, but when I try and test it out my IDE crashes. I don't know if it's my toString method, or my Add method, so here's my code. When I test the methods it my IDE doesnt print or return anything and quits working to the point I have to restart.

```
public void add(int index, String string){
Node newest=new Node(string,null);
Node temp;
temp=head;
newest.setNext(temp);
 for (int i=0;i<index-1;i++){     
     newest.setNext(newest.getNext());}


 for (int i=0;i<=index-1;i++){
     temp.setNext(temp.getNext());
     if (i==index-1){
     temp.setNext(newest);
     }
 }}

 public String toString(){
    Node Current= head;
    String result=" ";
    while(Current!=null){
    result+=Current.getElement()+", ";
    Current=Current.getNext();

        }
return result;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _crashes_?

Comment: I'll edit, but when I run an test of the methods in my IDE it runs then doesn't return anything and I have to restart it

Answer (score 1):

Your add method seems to set up a loop in the linked list, the relevant code lines being;

```
newest.setNext(temp);
...
temp.setNext(newest);
```

Your `toString()` just loops until it finds the end of the list, but since the list loops back infinitely once the loop has been added, it will never terminate.

As a side note, you also have some strange lines;

```
newest.setNext(newest.getNext());
...
temp.setNext(temp.getNext());
```

...which as far as I can see do absolutely nothing (ie they get the next node and set it as a next node).

Comment: So how would I fix this?

Comment: @trosy I suspect you're using `setNext` when you really just mean to store the next node in a variable while looping. Only change the nodes you really want to change, not while iterating to find the correct node. Stepping through simple test cases in the IDE's debugger is invaluable to get a grip on exactly what is happening.